# Group Multiple Values in Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to group the all field of a collection with unique total. Let's assume there is collection like this:

```
 id  country state operator
 121  IN       HR    AIRTEL
 212  IN       MH    AIRTEL
 213  US       LA    AT&T
 214  UK       JK    VODAFONE
```

Output should be like this:

```js
{
    "country": { "IN": 2, "US":1, "UK":1 }, 
    "state": { "HR":1, "MH":1, "LA":1, "JK": 1 }, 
    "operator": { "AIRTEL":2, "AT&T": 1, "VODAFONE": 1 }
}
```

I am trying to use mongo aggregation framework, but can't really think how to do this?

Comment: It is not possible using the `aggregation framework`. You need to use `Map-Reduce`.

Comment: @BatScream can you give some examples or links to refer?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/ - this should be a very simple and effective starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I find out some similar to your output using  aggregation check below code

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "countryOfIN": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$country", "IN"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "countryOfUK": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$country", "UK"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "countryOfUS": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$country", "US"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "stateOfHR": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$state", "HR"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "stateOfMH": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$state", "MH"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "stateOfLA": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$state", "LA"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "stateOfJK": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$state", "JK"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "operatorOfAIRTEL": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$operator", "AIRTEL"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "operatorOfAT&T": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$operator", "AT&T"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    },
    "operatorOfVODAFONE": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{
          $eq: ["$operator", "VODAFONE"]
        }, 1, 0]
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "country": {
      "$push": {
        "IN": "$countryOfIN",
        "UK": "$countryOfUK",
        "US": "$countryOfUS"
      }
    },
    "STATE": {
      "$push": {
        "HR": "$stateOfHR",
        "MH": "$stateOfMH",
        "LA": "$stateOfLA",
        "JK": "$stateOfJK"
      }
    },
    "operator": {
      "$push": {
        "AIRTEL": "$operatorOfAIRTEL",
        "AT&T": "$operatorOfAT&T",
        "VODAFONE": "$operatorOfVODAFONE"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "country": 1,
    "STATE": 1,
    "operator": 1
  }
})
```

using [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) created groups of matched data and pushed them in second groups to combine.

Answer (score 1):

An output format like you are looking for is not really suited to the aggregation framework since you are tranforming part of your data in to "key" names. The aggregation framework does not do this but rather sticks to database "best practice" as does not transform "data" to "key" names in any way.

You can perform a mapReduce operation instead with allows more flexibilty with the manipulation, but not as good performance due to the need to use JavaScript code to perform the manipulation:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function () {
    var obj = {},
        doc = this;

    delete doc._id;
    Object.keys(doc).forEach(function(key) {
      obj[key] = {};
      obj[key][doc[key]] = 1;
    });
    emit( null, obj );
  },
  function (key,values) {
    var result = {};

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      Object.keys(value).forEach(function(outerKey) {
        Object.keys(value[outerKey]).forEach(function(innerKey) {
          if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(outerKey) ) {
            result[outerKey] = {};
          }
          if ( result[outerKey].hasOwnProperty(innerKey) ) {
            result[outerKey][innerKey] += value[outerKey][innerKey];
          } else {
            result[outerKey][innerKey] = value[outerKey][innerKey];
          }
        });
      });
    });

    return result;
  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

And in the stucture that applies to all mapReduce results:

```js
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : null,
                    "value" : {
                            "country" : {
                                    "IN" : 2,
                                    "US" : 1,
                                    "UK" : 1
                            },
                            "state" : {
                                    "HR" : 1,
                                    "MH" : 1,
                                    "LA" : 1,
                                    "JK" : 1
                            },
                            "operator" : {
                                    "AIRTEL" : 2,
                                    "AT&T" : 1,
                                    "VODAFONE" : 1
                            }
                    }
            }
    ]
}
```

For the aggregation framework itself, it is better suited to producing aggregation results that are more consistently structured:

```js
db.mapex.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "country": 1,
        "state": 1,
        "operator": 1,
        "type": { "$literal": ["country","state","operator"] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "type": "$type",
           "key": { "$cond": {
               "if": { "$eq": [ "$type", "country" ] },
               "then": "$country",
               "else": { "$cond": {
                   "if": { "$eq": [ "$type", "state" ] },
                   "then": "$state",
                   "else": "$operator"
               }}
           }}
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which would output:

```js
{ "_id" : { "type" : "state", "key" : "JK" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "country", "key" : "UK" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "country", "key" : "US" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "operator", "key" : "AT&T" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "state", "key" : "LA" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "operator", "key" : "AIRTEL" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "state", "key" : "MH" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "state", "key" : "HR" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "operator", "key" : "VODAFONE" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "type" : "country", "key" : "IN" }, "count" : 2 }
```

But is fairly easy to transform in client code while iterating the results:

```js
var result = {};

db.mapex.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "country": 1,
        "state": 1,
        "operator": 1,
        "type": { "$literal": ["country","state","operator"] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "type": "$type",
           "key": { "$cond": {
               "if": { "$eq": [ "$type", "country" ] },
               "then": "$country",
               "else": { "$cond": {
                   "if": { "$eq": [ "$type", "state" ] },
                   "then": "$state",
                   "else": "$operator"
               }}
           }}
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
    if ( !result.hasOwnProperty(doc._id.type) )
        result[doc._id.type] = {};
    result[doc._id.type][doc._id.key] = doc.count;
})
```

Which gives the final structure in "result":

```js
{
    "state" : {
            "JK" : 1,
            "LA" : 1,
            "MH" : 1,
            "HR" : 1
    },
    "country" : {
            "UK" : 1,
            "US" : 1,
            "IN" : 2
    },
    "operator" : {
            "AT&T" : 1,
            "AIRTEL" : 2,
            "VODAFONE" : 1
    }
}
```